# Can I get a download link for my WPF application from Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm developing a Windows WPF application that I have set up a build pipeline for in Azure Devops. My problem is that I can't seem to figure out any way to download the artifacts after successfully completing the build.

Is it possible to get a link to a zip containing all the built files somehow. How can I get my files? I don't want to publish to NPM or NuGet or anything like that, just download to my desktop for now.

Thanks!

Edit: This is my build configuration

```
trigger:
- master

pr:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'VS2017-Win2016'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'x64'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@0
  displayName: 'NuGet Tool Installer'

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'Restore NuGet dependencies'
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build $(buildConfiguration) $(buildPlatform)'
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy files'
  inputs:
    Contents: '_buildOutput\\**\\*.dll'
    TargetFolder: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publishing artifact drop'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    artifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'filePath'
    targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\\outdir\\$(Build.DefinitionName)\\$(Build.BuildNumber)'

- task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
  inputs:
    buildType: 'current'
    downloadType: 'single'
    artifactName: 'drop'
    downloadPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'
```

Comment: Did you refer to the REST API documentation for build artifacts?

Comment: You may use DownloadBuildArtifacts for release and you do not need it for build definition.

Answer (score 4):

You may use 2 ways:

1. Copy the download link from the build results:
   [image]
2. Use link from this example ([Artifacts - Get Artifact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/artifacts/get%20artifact?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0)).

You need to know the Id for your build.

[image]

Then you may use download link with this format (for drop by default):

```
https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}/artifacts?artifactName=drop&api-version=5.0&%24format=zip
```

**Updates (if you use yaml):**

You have to use the "Publish Artifact" task if you want to work with build result and have the "Artifact" button.

You can publish it to Azure DevOps (by default):

```
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: 'Your folder with build results'
```

Also you can publish you results to the some file share:

```
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: 'Your folder with build results'
    publishLocation: FilePath
    TargetPath: '\\my\share\$(Build.DefinitionName)\$(Build.BuildNumber)'
```

**Updates 2:**

If try to download your with format:

```
https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}/artifacts?artifactName=drop&api-version=5.0
```

You will get json with urls:

[image]

You may add "&%24format=zip" to the end of url and get a zip file:

[image]

**Update 3**

This is the part of my yaml build definition that was converted from standard build:

```
- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(build.sourcesdirectory)'
    Contents: '**\bin\$(buildConfiguration)\**'
    TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
```

Comment: 1. I don't seem to have the Artifacts button. I'm looking at the Pipelines -> Build page.
2. Where can I finnd the artifactName? I know all the others. But without artifactName it's not working.

Thanks!

Comment: I think I might have found something useful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pipeline-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Comment: Yes, you have to use the publish artifact task to see the artifact button on build results. I`ve updated my answer.

Comment: Great! I'm making progress. But I'm just getting a json response when trying to download from the browser... Is it because I'm not setting the correct Content-Type correctly or am I missing something else?

Comment: Try to add &%24format=zip to your url. I`ve updated the answer.

Comment: That gives a 400 response with the message: The artifact type filepath is not supported.

Comment: even if copy it from the json? Or you use "filepath" to publish your build results?

Comment: I use filepath. Should I use Container instead?

Comment: Also, the Artifacts button only gives me a filepath (file:///D:/a/1/a//....) to copy. No download button.

Comment: If you use "publishLocation: FilePath" build agent publish build result to some location and you have to use some shared folder to get it. Without "publishLocation: FilePath" as in my first example in Update 2, build result will be published in internal storage and you can get a zip file.

Comment: If I remove FilePath the Artifacts button disappears. I've updated my question with my build yaml. See if that helps to identify my mistakes. It's probably more than one! :P